# After adding @ComponentScan to load beans from a jar my controllers isn't scan and i get 404

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, component-scan

I have a spring-boot application (Java8, spring-boot 2.1.4-RELEASE).

One of the services in the business layer need to @Autowire a bean from a certain jars in my classpath. In order to achieve that i had to add @ComponentScan({"package.to.my.bean.inside.the.jar"}) and it was magically scanned and wired successfully (this was added to the main spring-boot class which declare the main method).

However, **since then** my controllers aren't scanned hence the DispatcherServlet is returning 404 for every request i trigger (default dispatcher).
Actually my entire spring-boot app annotations is being ignored - no scan is performed.
Just to emphasis - the application worked perfectly before adding the @ComponentScan.

Main spring-boot app class:

```
package com.liav.ezer;

// This is the problematic addition that cause the endpoints to stop
// inside a jar in the classpath, in com.internal.jar package resides an 
// object which i need to wire at run time
@ComponentScan({"com.internal.jar"})
@SpringBootApplication
public class JobsApplication {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(JobsApplication .class, args);
        }
}
```

Controller example:

```
package com.liav.ezer.controller;

@RestController
@EnableAutoConfiguration
@RequestMapping(path = "/jobs")
public class JobController {

    @GetMapping(path="/create", produces = "application/json")
    @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.OK)
    String createJob(@RequestParam() String jobName) String jobName){       
        return "job created...";
    }
}
```

I tried adding my spring-boot app base package to the list of packages in the @ComponentScan with no luck. 
I tried narrowing down the scope of the package declaration to be only on the class which i need with no luck.
Here is the code

Comment: Add you controller package to @ComponentScan: `@ComponentScan({"com.internal.jar", "com.liav.ezer.controller"})

Comment: You told it to *only* scan `com.internal.jar`. Specifying a value *replaces* the default (package of containing class), it doesn't add to it. Please **read the documentation**, i.e. the javadoc of [`ComponentScan`](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/annotation/ComponentScan.html): *"If specific packages **are not defined**, scanning will occur from the package of the class that declares this annotation."*

Comment: Hi Andreas and Bor. As i wrote in the question - i did tried to add my base package to the list of scan (e.g @ComponentScan("com.internal.jar", "com.liav.ezer")) with no success. My controllers are still ignored

Comment: When adding my base package to the @CompoentScan my container fails to start and i get: ***************************
APPLICATION FAILED TO START
***************************

Description:

Field jobManager in com.liav.ezer.service.JobNotifier required a bean of type 'com.internal.jar.JobManager' that could not be found.

The injection point has the following annotations:
        - @org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)


Action:

Consider defining a bean of type 'com.internal.jar.JobManager' in your configuration.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If so, remove @ComponentScan, can declare that bean in yourself configuration. 
try below

```java
@SpringBootApplication
public class JobsApplication {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(JobsApplication .class, args);
        }
     @Bean
     public BeanInOtherJar xxBean(){
        return new com.internal.jar.XXX();
     }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Yuan, that indeed helped. Now both my Bean is auto-wired and my controllers are recognized!

Answer (score 2):

According to [Spring documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/annotation/ComponentScan.html)

> Configures component scanning directives for use with @Configuration
>   classes. Provides support parallel with Spring XML's
>    element. Either basePackageClasses() or
>   basePackages() (or its alias value()) may be specified to define
>   specific packages to scan. If specific packages are not defined,
>   scanning will occur from the package of the class that declares this
>   annotation.

In your case when you are adding

> @ComponentScan({"com.internal.jar"})
>   you are disabling scanning of 
>   com.liav.ezer.controller

To fix it you can do the following configuration

> @ComponentScan(basePackages = {"com.internal.jar", "com.liav.ezer.controller"})

Comment: Actualy this is a more correct answer than the accepted one.

Comment: @ComponentScan(basePackages = {"com.internal.jar", "com.liav.ezer.controller"})


this is the solution.

Comment: As i stated above in the comments this approach (list of packages) which i tried after reading the doc's hasn't worked. Not only that it didn't progressed me i made a regression that my internal jar bean hasn't been wired.

Comment: @LiavEzer is you class in com.internal.jar package annotated as Component or any other Spring stereotype? If no Spring can not create instance of this class with ComponentScan